# structure overloading with dimension

Tags: c++

```
struct Range
{
    size_t ndim;
    size_t stWorkSize[3];
    size_t stOffest[3];
    inline Range ( size_t work_size )
    {
        ndim = 1;
        stWorkSize [0] = work_size;
        stWorkSize [1] = stWorkSize [2] = 0;
        stOffest [0] = stOffest [1] = stOffest  [2] = 0;

    }

  inline Range ( size_t work_size[2] )
    {
        ndim = 2;
        stWorkSize [0] = work_size[0];
        stWorkSize [1] = work_size[1];
        stWorkSize [2] = 0;
        stOffest [0] = stOffest [1] = stOffest  [2] = 0;
    }
    inline Range ( size_t work_size[3] )
    {
        ndim = 3;
        stWorkSize [0] = work_size[0];
        stWorkSize [1] = work_size[1];
        stWorkSize [2] = work_size[2];
        stOffest [0] = stOffest [1] = stOffest  [2] = 0;
    }

} ;
```

I hava a structure defines as above suggest me how to overload with dimension of the constructor
compiler gives me an error Range::Range(size_t *) cannot be overloader
is there any method to do like this

Answer (score 1):

One of approaches is the following

```
  inline Range ( const size_t ( &work_size )[2] )
    {
        ndim = 2;
        stWorkSize [0] = work_size[0];
        stWorkSize [1] = work_size[1];
        stWorkSize [2] = 0;
        stOffest [0] = stOffest [1] = stOffest  [2] = 0;
    }
    inline Range ( const size_t ( &work_size )[3] )
    {
        ndim = 3;
        stWorkSize [0] = work_size[0];
        stWorkSize [1] = work_size[1];
        stWorkSize [2] = work_size[2];
        stOffest [0] = stOffest [1] = stOffest  [2] = 0;
    }
```

Or simply define one constructor

```
  inline Range ( const size_t *work_size, size_t n );
```

Comment: we can use dimensional pointers also, similarly as you have use references